# How to provide unchecked weight to a call using Polkadot.js?

Tags: polkadot-js, extrinsic, weight

Unfortunately, I could not find how to add *unchecked weight* to a call via Polkadot.js, e.g. within `signAndSend` or when preparing the unsigned extrinsic. Even in the [cookbook example for runtime upgrades](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/examples/promise/upgrade-chain), it is not mentioned.

I am trying to fix the following error when calling `api.tx.configuration.setValidationUpgradeDelay(5)` with sudo by adding unchecked weight:

```
/app/node_modules/@polkadot/rpc-provider/coder/index.cjs:76
      throw new _error.default(fmtMessage, code, data);
            ^

RpcError: 1010: Invalid Transaction: Transaction would exhaust the block limits
```

Comment: You may be looking for `sudo.sudoUncheckedWeight` as opposed to `sudo.sudo`

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe Jaco's comment above points to the right answer, at least I cannot find a reference to unchecked weight elsewhere. So I dug a bit into code and docs.

That led me to looking at the JS UI as well, specifically the sudo page and the "with weight" option there. Specifying it indeed calls the [sudo.sudoUncheckedWeight](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/blob/ffe763f28bfe7feea1342eb0a7bea7df9b6cf190/packages/page-sudo/src/Sudo.tsx#L81-L85) with the specified weight in the params as per the [extrinsic definition](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/extrinsics#sudouncheckedweightcall-call-weight-u64).

You should be able to do -

```js
/* the weight we want to use, unchecked */
const weight = 1

/* the upgrade we want to send */
const upgrade = api.tx.system.setCode("0x...")

/* make the upgrade, unchecked */
const sudo = api.tx.sudo.sudoUncheckedWeight(upgrade, weight)

/* send sudo here with signAndSend */
...
```