# Upgrade Rococo fork, error would exhaust block limits (no pallet_scheduler)

Tags: polkadot, rococo, rococo-local

We're trying to upload a Rococo fork, it seems that Rococo doesn't have pallet_scheduler out the box, so we don't have that option.

```
sudo.sudo 
1010: Invalid transaction:
Transaction would exhaust the block limits
```

I'm using the `rococo_runtime.compact.compressed.wasm` bin which is only 971KB.

Is there anyway we can force the upgrade?

Answer (score 3):

Put through the upgrade with `sudo.sudoUncheckedWeight` instead of `sudo.sudo`.

If using the apps UI, the sudo page does have a toggle to swap this this second call aka the "with weight override" toggle enables this call to be used.

Comment: Thank you that worked. I used the `setSudoWithoutChecks(code)` extrinsic. I nominally added weight as 1. Does it matter what weight is added there? assuming the "without check" overlooks it anyway.

Comment: You bypass the weight check and specify your own, so it can be nominal. Here is a link to the Substrate implementation & description for it - https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/184d29caf8302053fac74ad74cd68bf43572108e/frame/sudo/src/lib.rs#L156-L158

Comment: Here is a previous question with JS code around the same execution strategy - https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1253/how-to-provide-unchecked-weight-to-a-call-using-polkadot-js/1324#1324