# Why Transaction would exhaust the block limits

Tags: substrate-node-template

locally we are not getting this issue but in tanssi getting this issue `RPC-CORE: submitAndWatchExtrinsic(extrinsic: Extrinsic): ExtrinsicStatus:: 1010: Invalid Transaction: Transaction would exhaust the block limits,` what could be the problem?

I found [this solutions](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1639/upgrade-rococo-fork-error-would-exhaust-block-limits-no-pallet-scheduler/1640#1640) but I don't understand. It says to use `sudo.sudoUncheckedWeight instead of sudo.sudo`, where to use this and when?

[image]

Comment: Do you have code/benchmark weights to share for this extrinsic? Probably exceeding the weight allowed for that extrinsic.