# Transaction would exhaust the block limits

Tags: weight, polkadot-launch, ui

Trying to run transaction in Polkadot.js.org UI

This method in UI

```
  const insertKeys = async (api: ApiPromise, seed: string, publicKey: string) => {
  const insert = await api.rpc.author.insertKey("orac", seed, publicKey);
  console.log("  Insert Keys  ");
  console.log(` ${publicKey}`);
  console.log(" Successful");
};
```

with this parameters

```
api.rpc.author.insertKey("orac", "recall inhale trick wasp core hat problem season february buzz juice cloth", "0x4cc5f1b01d843ede8cca27dd4b9be4408ca9459aca36d2240666a2479a900a1d")
```

But getting error

[image]

Comment: `insertKey` is a rpc and not a transaction. So, you can not get this error for calling a rpc.

Comment: The error you are showing seems to come from a runtime upgrade, not setting keys for a node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have commented, you seem to be looking at 2 different results.

On the error - this generally happens when you don't specify enough weight on the runtime upgrade, i.e. `setCode` transaction. There are actually a couple of existing questions that deal with this:

- [setting the weight programatically](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1253/how-to-provide-unchecked-weight-to-a-call-using-polkadot-js/1324#1324) and
- [setting the weight via the
  UI](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1639/upgrade-rococo-fork-error-would-exhaust-block-limits-no-pallet-scheduler/1640#1640) (unchecked sudo checkbox)

Doing either of these will get around the error message.

Comment: Thanks  it was helpful